# error: when getting started with facebook application by Heroku

Tags: facebook, git, command-line, heroku

When I enter `$git remote` the command line responds with:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Not sure what to do, and any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Heroku's [Deploying with Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).

1. Set up your Git repository.
2. Add the `heroku` remote.
3. Deploy your code.

You need to initialize whatever code project directory you are using to track with Git. Then, you need to add a Git remote (typically called `heroku`) to point to a Heroku Git remote repository. Then, you can fetch and push code to that repository. Then Heroku uses that repository to deploy your application to your servers.

I think the Heroku documentation will be of the most help to you!

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git